# jquery scrolltop won't check when document loaded

Tags: jquery

i want to check if a document is scrolled to an amount of pixels in relation to my navigation (nav):

```
$(function(){
    var stickyMenuTop = $('nav').offset().top + 100;

        $(window).on("scroll load",function(e){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyMenuTop ) {
                $('nav').addClass('scrollto')
                $('.navi-top').addClass('scrollto')
                $('.navi-top a').css('opacity', '1' )
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('scrollto')
                $('.navi-top').removeClass('scrollto')
                $('.navi-top a').css('opacity', '0' )
            }
        });

    });
```

it works but when i reload the page and i have scrolled down before it doesn't work. i have to scroll to top first then reload. how can i do it that if i reload the page when i have already scrolled down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$(function(){
    var stickyMenuTop = 100;

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > stickyMenuTop ) {
            $('nav').addClass('scrollto');
            $('.navi-top').addClass('scrollto');
            $('.navi-top a').css('opacity', '1' );
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('scrollto');
            $('.navi-top').removeClass('scrollto');
            $('.navi-top a').css('opacity', '0' );
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9fg6/3/

You actually don't need to check on document load.

Comment: Add all semicolons you forgot, and check the console for syntax error ;)

Comment: http://herrfischerhamburg.de/_jsfiddle/scrolltop/ it stoll won't work with your code. it checks the actual scroll position i think and THAN adds 100 when i reload the page after i scrolled down to the bottom.

Comment: Works fine on my Windows / Chrome. What browser / OS are you using ?

Comment: Ok it bugs on Firefox. I'm on it.

Comment: yes you are right, it bugs only on firefox, other browsers are fine ... . i am using firefox on windows machine.

Comment: I changed the code above. Actually, you don't need to check your navbar offset top, because it will allways be 0. Works fine in Firefox.

Comment: But that's a good question. On reload, Firefox don't go top then scroll (and trigger the scroll()), it already is on the scrolled position. I think it's a new feature.

Comment: okay but it looks logical, it only checks "scrollTop" and that's it -  thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes but $(document).scrollTop() is used to check the distance the scrollbar made. In your case, on reload, Firefox thinks $(document).scrollTop() is 0 when he is on the middle of the page... Even if we scroll.